# AEM 6.1 : ACS AEM commons bundle - multifield

Tags: aem, aem-6

I am using AEM 6.1 and using the multifield provided by the acs aem commons version 2.2 bundle. I want to limit the number of multifield that I can configure. I have gone through the documentation [here](https://adobe-consulting-services.github.io/acs-aem-commons/features/widgets.html) but nothing seems to be working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So just found out it works by adding a maxItems property on the multifield node. Earlier I was trying to use that property on multifieldpanel node.

Answer (score 4):

By  minItems="1"
    maxItems="1" 
you can set the maximum and minimum number of items.